# I wasn't planning on it

Tags: word-usage

Could you please tell me what the following phrase mean?

Does it mean: I wasn't expecting it or something else? What would you use it for?

What does : "I wasn't planning on it." Mean?

Comment: http://www.omnilexica.com/?q=to+plan+on

Comment: It's a kind of compressed version of *I wasn't **counting** on it **in my planning**.* Not quite the same as *I wasn't **expecting** it* - more like *I knew it was **possible**, but either I thought it was unlikely OR I didn't think I needed to adjust my plans to allow for it anyway*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both "I didn't plan on it" and "I wasn't planning on it" can mean that "it" is something the speaker didn't *expect*, or something they didn't *intend*.  Both of these imply that the speaker has some kind of a *plan*, but the response to the plan can vary.  You have to determine from context which is meant.

For example, something unexpected:

> **I wasn't planning** on the cops showing up just as I came out of the front door of the bank," said the burglar to his cellmate.

Something unintended:

> **I wasn't planning** to go out through the roof," the burglar said, "but then the cops showed up just as I was going out the front door of the bank."

It's similar when talking about a future condition.  Example:

> A: Will you have to cut the event short due to inclement weather?
>
> B: We aren't planning on it, as the forecast calls for clear skies. (we don't *expect* there will be a problem)

or

> B:  We aren't planning on it, as we can move the event inside if it rains.  (we don't *intend* that there should be a problem)